# Add font in label in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

Actually this question has been answered multiple times but i don't know where i am stucking. i have tried this.
[image: in info.plist i have added museo700]

[image: Then after i have added in bundle resources.]

and then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    lbl_openHouse = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 120)];
    lbl_openHouse.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    lbl_openHouse.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo700-Regular" size:35];
}
```

But not working.
Even i have tried this to find actual name of font but not displayed in log.

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

[image: I have also edited. still not working]

Comment: I guess, you are missing to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35454097/1603234), let me know if it will help you.

Comment: Your plist seems wrong. It doesn't seem that the font is INSIDE the array "Fonts provided by application". The arrow is closed but it still displaying the value.

Comment: i have edited but still not workin..

Comment: Even i can see my font in font book. @Hemang

Answer (score 0):

In your plist you need to add like this

[image]

You have not properly added them in your plist. Your fonts are outside the `Fonts provided by the application`

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded the font from this [link](http://fontsforweb.com/font/show?id=14464) and installed it. its actual name is `Museo700regular.ttf`
i added it to .plist like below:

[image]

in my application it looks like:

[image]

the reason is probably with actual font name for you.

Comment: i have installed from all top ten google answer, but still not getting.. . :-)

Comment: i think there is only problem with Museo700, i have tried for other,  all are working..