# IOS 8, custom font issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I added a custom Chinese font to my project, (followed the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)). I only want to set the font for a few buttons, but when i do this in code or in storyboard, all the other labels, buttons, textFields.. are all set to this font too. And this only happens to ios8, and it works fine on ios9. Why did this happen, can anyone help?

this is my code to set the font:

```
UIFont *hannotate = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hannotate SC" size:18];
self.button1.titleLabel.font = hannotate;
self.button2.titleLabel.font = hannotate;
```

this is what i set in storyboard:

[image]

**Updation1:**

this is screenshot of my Info.plist, I have change the font name everywhere to "FHTHannotateSC".

[image]

**Updation2**

I printed all the fonts in ios 8 system, and found i was using the font family name(Hannotate SC) as the font name, the real font name is "HannotateSC-W5", so i corrected the font name, and run the APP again, but unluckily, the font is still global set.

Comment: please check this link here you could find few common mistakes while adding custom font http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: Your code seems good. Try changing the font name.

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan I changed the font name to a very unique one, but the problem still remands. Thanks for your advice anyway.

Comment: Can you show me your info.plist ? The name you've given in plist for the font should be given in code.

Comment: @morroko Thanks for your comment,  I read though the post, but didn't see any similar question, any other advice?

Comment: Try changing the font name to FHTHannotateSC and try again.

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan maybe it's not a matter of font name, it's like a matter that something with trigger the ios 8 system to set the font as global.

Comment: First log all fonts available in you xcode. And check are you using right name. refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090916/fonts-on-ios-device

Comment: see the target member ship of that font by click font and see right side

Comment: @RahulMishra Thanks for your advice, i did find a problem with the font name, but the problem still remands even if i corrected the font name.

Comment: Please do let me know if my this answer help you finding out the real name of a [font](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35454097/1603234). @MudOnTire

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the `appearance` proxy anywhere in your app like this: `[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HannotateSC-W5" size:17.0]];` ?

Comment: @atulkhatri no, I'm so sure of that. thanks

Comment: @Hemang thanks for your answer, I will give it a try tomorrow as I am off work now.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by doing following steps:
1. Go to project target
2. Choose Build Phase option
3. Add the font files in Copy Bundle resources.

May this help you!

Comment: Hi dude, I have already done that, or the font can't not be set to any UI widgets. The problem is the system did much more I want it to do. I only want 2 buttons to use the font, but now other labels, buttons are forced to use the font.